# how to keep a circle centered during animation

Tags: python, android, animation, graphics, kivy

hellow guys, I'm developing a Chwazi clown using python kivy application.
quick background: in this app there are is a circle when you press (and hold and it beats (gets bigger and smaller))
I came across a problem with animation of the beating, because when i use this function:

```
def beat_animation(self, circle):
        anim = Animation(size=(circle.size[0]*1.2, circle.size[1]*1.2), duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(size=(circle.size[0], circle.size[1]), duration=0.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(circle)
```

my circle is getting bigger and smaller as I want it to be, but the problem is that it does not stay centered around the cursor.
(this is meant to be an app and it supports multitouch, so it should be doing it to all the circles)

here is the full code:

```
import random

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation


class Touch(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.circles = {}  # Dictionary to store circles for each finger

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.id not in self.circles:
            with self.canvas:
                width, height = self.size  # Get the screen size
                circle_size = min(width, height) * 0.3  # Calculate the circle size as 10% of the smaller dimension of the screen
                color = Color(random.random(),random.random() ,random.random() ,1.0) #random color for the circle
                circle = Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - circle_size/2, touch.y - circle_size/2), size=(circle_size, circle_size))
                self.circles[touch.id] = (color, circle)
                self.beat_animation(circle)


    def beat_animation(self, circle):
        anim = Animation(size=(circle.size[0]*1.2, circle.size[1]*1.2), duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(size=(circle.size[0], circle.size[1]), duration=0.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(circle)


    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        width, height = self.size  # Get the screen size
        circle_size = min(width,height) * 0.3  # Calculate the circle size as 10% of the smaller dimension of the screen
        if touch.id in self.circles:
            color, circle = self.circles[touch.id]
            circle.pos = (touch.x - circle_size/2, touch.y - circle_size/2)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.id in self.circles:
            color, circle = self.circles.pop(touch.id)
            self.canvas.remove(color)
            self.canvas.remove(circle)

class MultiTouchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Touch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MultiTouchApp().run()
```

i tried to add change it like so:

```
    def beat_animation(self, circle, touch):
        anim = Animation(pos=(touch.x - circle.size[0] / 2, touch.y - circle.size[1] / 2),size=(circle.size[0] * 1.2, circle.size[1] * 1.2), duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(pos=(touch.x - circle.size[0] / 2, touch.y - circle.size[1] / 2),size=(circle.size[0] / 1.2, circle.size[1] / 1.2), duration=0.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(circle)
```

but then when i stop moving my finger, the circle just jumps back to the location it was first created (i think it is because the touch parameter that is passed to beat_animation is not changing dynamically) and I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

A general way to solve this type of problem is to use a property that serves as an intermediary between the animation and the canvas instruction.

In this case, I think that the simplest way to achieve what you want is split each circle into a separate widget and use a `FloatLayout` as a parent:

```
import random

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ColorProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class BeatingTouchCircle(Widget):    
    radius = NumericProperty(1)
    position = ListProperty([0, 0])
    color = ColorProperty((0, 0, 0, 1))
    
    def __init__(self, radius, position, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.radius = radius
        self.position = position
        self.color = color
        
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba = self.color)
            self.circle = Ellipse(
                pos = (self.position[0] - self.radius, self.position[1] - self.radius),
                size = (self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2)
                )
            
        self.beat_animation()
        self.bind(radius=self.on_radius_changed)
        
    def beat_animation(self):
        anim = Animation(radius = self.radius * 1.2, duration = 0.5)
        anim += Animation(radius = self.radius, duration = 0.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)
        
    def on_radius_changed(self, *_):
        self.circle.size = (self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2)
        self.circle.pos = (self.position[0] - self.radius, self.position[1] - self.radius)        



class Touch(FloatLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.circles = {}  # Dictionary to store circles for each finger

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.id not in self.circles:
            radius = min(self.size) * 0.15
            color = (random.random(),random.random() ,random.random() ,1.0) #random color for the circle
            circle = BeatingTouchCircle(radius, (touch.x, touch.y), color)
            self.circles[touch.id] = (circle, touch)
            self.add_widget(circle)
            
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if circle := self.circles.get(touch.id):
            circle, touch = circle
            circle.position = (touch.x, touch.y)
            
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if circle := self.circles.get(touch.id):
            self.remove_widget(circle[0])
            del self.circles[touch.id]
            

class MultiTouchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Touch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MultiTouchApp().run()
```

[image]